# Creating transparent overlays for horizontal row of 3 <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to cause an overlay on mouseover for my three images. I believe it will be best to use jQuery after creating a div. However, when I add a new div to my layout (below each of the `<img>` in my code) My layout is screwed up; goes from horizontal list to  vertical list if i try to add in any `<div>` below my `<img>`.

**I mainly want the overlay just sitting there. Im sure I can figure out mouseover action, but main issue is I cannot generate initial overlay**

stackoverflowers: please help me add in an overlay div that will ultimately be transparent.

home.html **I have commented out my attempt at placing overlay divs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link type = "text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <title>Home Page</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <ul id="headerMenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">PROGRAM</a>
                <ul id="programDrop">
                    <li><a href='#'>INSPECTIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>SOFTWARE</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>SAVINGS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a>
                 <ul id="loginDrop">
                    <li><a href='#'>TECHNICIAN LOGIN</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>CUSTOMER LOGIN</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="midMain">
        <div class="circularImg">
            <img src="http://media.treehugger.com/assets/images/2011/10/ice-energy-store.jpg"/>
            <!-- <div class="overlay"></div> -->
            <img src="http://www.contemporist.com/photos/e4delmar.jpg"/>
            <!-- <div class="overlay"></div> -->
            <img src="http://www.rkmheatingandair.com/service-tech2.jpg"/>
            <!-- <div class="overlay"></div> -->
        </div>
    </div>

</body>



</html>
```

stylesheet.css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

/* Main centered menu on top */

    #headerMenu {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

#headerMenu > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#headerMenu > li:nth-child(1) {
    color:red;   
}

#headerMenu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin: 2rem;
    padding: 0;
    }

#headerMenu li a:hover {
    color: lightgray;
}

/* Sub Menu for Link One */
  #programDrop {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    position:absolute;
}

#programDrop li a{
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
}

/* Sub Menu for Link Two */

#loginDrop {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    position:absolute;
}

#loginDrop li a{
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
}


/* Photos on home page */
#midMain {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.circularImg {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Removed code because nothing works as of yet */
.overLay {

}

/* Sets img imports as circular by default */
img {
    border-radius: 50em;
    min-height: 10em;
    height: 18em;
    width: 18em;
    min-width: 10em;
    margin: 3rem;
    position:relative;
    opacity: .5;
    }
```

included jQuery script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('#headerMenu > li:nth-child(1)').mouseenter(function() {
   $('#programDrop').css('visibility','visible'); 
});
$('#headerMenu > li:nth-child(1)').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#programDrop').css('visibility','hidden'); 
});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('#headerMenu > li:nth-child(2)').mouseenter(function() {
   $('#loginDrop').css('visibility','visible'); 
});
$('#headerMenu > li:nth-child(2)').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#loginDrop').css('visibility','hidden');
});
});
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a JSfiddle to play around with?

Comment: Put the the images inside the overlay divs and give the overlays a higher z-index value, copy the exact css from the images to the overlay and remove the margin for the images -- demo, http://jsfiddle.net/8zv5yyrw/  -- if this is what you are after ill put it as an answer

Comment: this is with the mouseover function -- http://jsfiddle.net/79zty3h7/

Comment: @Tasos thanks for he help. BTW, adding a display:inline-block fixes all alignment issues. Add as question and will accept as answer

Answer (score 1):

As per comments

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
    background:black;
    border-radius: 50em;
    min-height: 10em;
    height: 18em;
    width: 18em;
    min-width: 10em;
    margin: 3rem;
    position:relative;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="overlay"><img src="http://media.treehugger.com/assets/images/2011/10/ice-energy-store.jpg"/></div>
```

**CODE**

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "img", function() {
 $(".overlay").css({"z-index": "999"});               
 $("img").css("opacity",".5");             
});
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/79zty3h7/